# Bezier path function by multiple points with native javascript

Tags: javascript, bezier

I need bezier function by several points and separate it for some steps. Imagine a pirate map with a dashed line :) I have a single dash (some display object with x/y position and rotation ) for building this map

I found canvas methods `.quadraticCurveTo()` etc, but i need specific function to separate curve to steps

I used earlier native function for base bezier curve

```js
function bezier(t, p0, p1, p2, p3){
  var cX = 3 * (p1.x - p0.x),
      bX = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x) - cX,
      aX = p3.x - p0.x - cX - bX;

  var cY = 3 * (p1.y - p0.y),
      bY = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y) - cY,
      aY = p3.y - p0.y - cY - bY;

  var x = (aX * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bX * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cX * t) + p0.x;
  var y = (aY * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bY * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cY * t) + p0.y;

  return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

But I don't know could I to use this for my problem, because i have only initial array with simple points `[{x:0, y:0}, {x:-30, y:-50}, {x:-10, y:-100}, {x:-30, y:-150}]` (without bezier control points)

Please, help me to calculate control points for soft path

Comment: This doesn't look like the Bezier function at all? For a cubic curve (since you show four points), it's `a(1-t)³ + 3bt(1-t)² + 3ct²(1-t) + dt³` where a, b, c, and d are your coordinate values. Also the Canvas2D API supports cubic beziers using `bezierCurveTo()` so there isn't even any reason to manually compute any curve coordinates. So with all that said, give https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo a look-over.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the control points for a point based on the points before and after:

```
function cp(a, b, c) {
  if (!a || !c) return b;
  return {
    x: b.x + (c.x - a.x) * .25,
    y: b.y + (c.y - a.y) * .25
  };
}
```

and the respective bezier functions

```
function bezier4(t,a,b,c,d) {
  var u = 1-t, fa = u*u*u, fb = 3*u*u*t, fc = 3*u*t*t, fd = t*t*t;
  return {
    x: a.x*fa + b.x*fb + c.x*fc + d.x*fd
    y: a.y*fa + b.y*fb + c.y*fc + d.y*fd
  };
}

function bezier(t, ...points) {
  var last = points.length-1;
  t *= last;

  if(t <= 0) return points[0];
  if(t >= last) return points[last];
  var i = Math.floor(t);
  if(t === i) return points[i];

  return bezier4(
    t-i,
    points[i],
    cp(points[i-1], points[i], points[i+1]),
    cp(points[i+2], points[i+1], points[i]),
    points[i+1]
  );
}
```

and a little snippet taking the points and creating a svg.

```js
var points = [{x:0, y:0}, {x:-30, y:-50}, {x:-10, y:-100}, {x:-30, y:-150}];

function cp(a, b, c) {
  if (!a || !c) return b;
  return {
    x: b.x + (c.x - a.x) * .25,
    y: b.y + (c.y - a.y) * .25
  };
}

var pointsWithControlPoints = points.flatMap((pt, i) => [
    cp(points[i + 1], pt, points[i - 1]),
    pt,
    cp(points[i - 1], pt, points[i + 1]),
  ])
  .slice(1, -1) // remove the control points before the first point and after the last one
  .map(pt => [pt.x, pt.y]);

var bounds = points.reduce((bounds, pt) => {
  bounds.top = Math.min(bounds.top, pt.y);
  bounds.left = Math.min(bounds.left, pt.x);
  bounds.bottom = Math.max(bounds.bottom, pt.y);
  bounds.right = Math.max(bounds.right, pt.x);
  return bounds;
}, {
  top: points[0].x,
  left: points[0].y,
  bottom: points[0].x,
  right: points[0].y
});
bounds.width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
bounds.height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

document.body.innerHTML = `<svg 
  viewBox="${bounds.left-10} ${bounds.top-10} ${bounds.width+20} ${bounds.height+20}"
  width="${bounds.width+20}"
  height="${bounds.height+20}"
>
  <path fill="none" 
    stroke="black" 
    stroke-dasharray="4" 
    d="M${pointsWithControlPoints[0]}C${pointsWithControlPoints.slice(1)}" 
    />
  ${points.map(pt => `<rect x="${pt.x - 4}" y="${pt.y - 4}" width="8" height="8" />`).join("\n")}
</svg>`;
```

Comment: Thanks! I  have coded something similar. But I have one more problem: It is different spaces between dashes https://prnt.sc/pdwro4 (4 curves in my case with different length) I want join all curves like one and to position 25 dashes on them

Comment: I think it is possible to calculate curve length with some iterations of bezier function